# How To Adjust IFrame Height on Its Content

Tags: html

How To Adjust IFrame Height on Its Content? I have tried lot of codes from my search,but nothing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the content of the iframe is within the same domain as the main page.

If they are on the same domain then you could add some JavaScript to the iframe content page to pass the height of the content back to the main page.

If they are on different domains then browser security prohibits the two pages from communicating via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Its working fine with same domain.But i have to  show data from different domain.Is there any way to show that?

Comment: Do you have control over the content in the iframe? If so, you could add some JavaScript that uses AJAX (or SJAX) to send the size of the content to your server, and you could add some JavaScript on the main page to poll the server for the size, and adjust the size of the iframe once received.